# Index the ID number in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have an ArrayList that is taken from a .txt file. It displays the following details:

```
Id
Car Manufacturer
Car Type
Colour
*blank line*
```

For Example:

```
21
Vauxhall
Corsa
red

19
Vauxhall
Corsa
blue

18
Vauxhall
Corsa
White
```

I am curious as how to make the Id the "index" of an ArrayList, so that if a car was deleted or added to the Arraylist, It would automatically adjust the Id number.

Comment: Maybe use a `HashMap` instead...

Comment: Arraylists don't have allow arbitrary, non-contiguous indexes. A `Map` of some flavour would be better.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: `Stack records = new Stack();` - don't use raw types: `Stack<Album> records = new Stack<>();`. Also, I think you might mean `\n`, rather than `/n`.

Comment: This depending on the range of your ID field, what if the first one is `1` but the second one is `99999`, this will be bad for array. So you could try to use `Map` or `HashTable`

Comment: @AndyTurner by the way `Stack` extends `Vector`, which is kind of deprecated for new Java applications (only kept in the JDK for backward compatibility)

Comment: @Dici kind of deprecated, [but not formally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#class). Even so, it's not unsafe to use, unlike raw types.

Comment: @AndyTurner yep, I was just adding to your comment

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the ID as a primary Key for that ArrayList. You can do that by creating an ArrayList that is contains HashMap objects

`ArrayList<HashMap<int, CarObject>> = new ArrayList()`

Sorting then becomes a question of iterating through the integer IDs in your ArrayList Objects

Answer (score 0):

You using wrong DataStructure... For your purpose something like HashMap or LinkedHashMap would be more optimal. You can put all your car data in pojos

```
class Car {
int Id;
String make, style, color; 
getters/setters....; 
}
List<Car> list = myReadMethod();

//Then you make 
Map<int, Car> myCars = new HashMap<Int, Car>;
for(Car car : list)
     myCars.put(car.getId, car);
```